# Почему static_assert внутри класса не срабатывает?

Tags: c++, классы, static-assert

Почему этот код компилируется?

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 5);
};

A<int>* a;
```

Comment: А почему он не должен компилироваться? Это же не рантайм проверка!

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что `static_assert` никак не повлияет на то, что будет лежать в объектном файле?

Comment: @megorit если исходник не скомпилируется, то и объектного файла не будет. Причём тут это? Не должен компилироваться, потому что проверка времени компиляции. Если бы была рантайм, то все ошибки компиляции уже прошли энивей.

Comment: При том, что `static_assert` может быть почти где угодно, это не statement.

Comment: @megorit допустим, но я не понимаю, как это связано с вопросом.

Comment: Пойдём от обратного. Почему по-вашему это не должно работать?

Comment: А, соряны, я понял. Просмотрел суть)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо потому, что для создания указателя тело класса (и вообще наличие определения класса) неважно.

Если написать просто `A<int> a;`, то все срабатывает.

---

Это еще одна причина (кроме делания класса SFINAE-friendly) использовать `requires`:

```
template <class T> requires(sizeof(T) == 5)
struct A {...};
```

Comment: Лучше всё-таки писать концепт полноценный, каряво это выглядит ведь